# Applying Kalman filter for road lane detection

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, kalman-filter

I'm trying to implement a Kalman filter for road lane detection. As I currently have code that calculates the vanishing point using the hough transform and RANSAC. The vanishing point is then used to calculate the inverse perspective map. However the inverse perspective map is jittery And I would like to get a more stable output. To do this I want to stabilise my lane detection by applying a Kalman Filter. I was hoping someone could describe the process or provide an example specifically for lane detection?

Comment: While there are undoubtably a few applications of Kalman filters for that, Google or BMW are not going to share their code here.  But it sounds like your problem might in fact be that you're trying too big a task at once. Just create a test signal `f(t) = A*sin(2*pi*t/T) + noise` with `|noise|<A`, and then implement a Kalman filter for just that.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more explicit. I'm more interested in the general approach, do you assume that the hough lines would intercept the bottom margin of the image at almost the same point and use a Kalman filter for smoothing that signal out? and then later implement something for curved roads etc.